# Is there a way in sendmail of node.js to check invalid email address?

Tags: node.js, email, sendmail

I have a mailing system written using sendmail module of node js. It is working fine when I am sending a list of valid email address to its tolist. However, if one of the email address is wrong or non-existing , then it does not send any mail to the other email addresses even which are valid.

Below is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var sendmail = require('sendmail')();

router.post('/sendmail', function (req,res, next) {
    var html = req.body.html;
    var to   = req.body.to;
    var cc   = req.body.cc;
    var sub  = req.body.sub;

    sendmail({
      from:'mark@mymail.com',
      to: to,
      cc: cc,
      subject: sub,
      html: html,
    }, function(err, reply) {
        if(err) {
           res.send(err);
        } else {
           res.send("ok");
           return;
         }
     });
```

Now, let us assume that a good tolist looks like below:

smith@mymail.com, john@mymail.com, roger@mymail.com

If any of the above email id is wrongly spelled or is not existing then at the server I am getting error as below:

"Address rejected."
SMTP responds error code 550

Is there a mechanism in sendmail to check at the server side that  if such error is occurring, then at least to send the mail to the correct email address and throw error for the non-existing/wrong email address.

Comment: Mail errors are a complex issue. In some cases you'll have an error right away, in others the e-mail will go through at first, and you'll get a return e-mail for any error, which can happen from seconds to days later... In any case I would not recommend formatting an e-mail yourself as you do here. Use nodemailer or something equivalent to do the work for you, it'll handle a lot of special cases a lot better than you do.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for your reply. I tried with nodemailer the same way I implemented with sendmail. Could you please suggest me what would I put inside nodemailer.createTransport(' ' ) . I am not making it work due to that as of now and have no idea what should I put into that. Seeing my above example if you can help me would be great. Is it mandatory to provide a userid & password into nodemailer.createTransport(' ' ) ?

Comment: @jcaron  Even after providing my login a/c and password , I get error as 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mymail.com

Comment: You should provide the address of your SMTP (outgoing) server, or possibly localhost if you have one running on the same server, which is probably the case. or you can use the sendmail transport: https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/